# React Native ListView scrollTo prop not working

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native, scrollto

I am very new to React Native. I am trying to render a simple `listView` and scroll it to a particular position after it's loaded. For that, I have written the following code:

```
<ListView
        ref="listView"
        contentInset={{ top: 64, bottom: 0 }}
        onLayout={(event) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.refs.listView.scrollTo({x: 0, y: -64, animated: false})
          }, 1)
        }}
        contentOffset={{ y: -64, x: 0 }}
        contentContainerStyle={[
          Platform.OS !== "ios" ? androidStyles.listView : null
        ]}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        dataSource={this.props.listings}
        renderHeader={() => {........
```

I am always getting the following error: `Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of undefined` and `Unhandled JS Exception: Cannot read property 'scrollTo' of undefined`.

The error screen shot on simulator:

[image]

Where am I going wrong? What should I do to get the desired output?

P.S.: We can't handle this in `componentDidMount()` because the ListView is conditionally rendered.

Comment: What is the version of your react-native?

Comment: `react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.48.4`

Comment: can you try to change ref to `ref={(listview) => {this.listview = listview;}}` and `this.refs.listView.scrollTo(...)` to `this.listView.scrollTo(...)`

Comment: `<ListView
            ref={(listview) => {this.listview = listview;}}
            contentInset={{ top: 64, bottom: 0 }}
            onLayout={(event) => {
              this.listView.scrollTo({x: 0, y: -64, animated: false})
            }}
            contentOffset={{ y: -64, x: 0 }}` same issue persists

Comment: ListView is deprecated, btw. React native recommends using a FlatList now.